# Java: why "throw new Exception()" have to "add Exception to method signature" but "throw new RuntimeException()" not

Tags: java, syntax, intellij-idea

i try

```
package ro.ex;

/**
 * Created by roroco on 11/4/14.
 */

class Ex {

    public void m() {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public void m2() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

in `throw new Exception();`, intellij idea raise "Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception", but in `throw new RuntimeException();` it's not, **my question is:** what cause this diff?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html

Comment: RuntimeException is a un-checked exception i.e. the compiler does not check for its handling at compile time. On the other hand, a checked exception is checked by the compiler and must be either handled explicitly or declared on the method. Now why these exceptions exist in Java is a matter related to design choice of the language itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190175/14955

Answer (score 3):

See this [link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Exceptions.html) about checked and unchecked exceptions

[image]