# In Java, are there any Exceptions that are thrown by default to the caller, even if you don't specify them with "throws"

Tags: java, exception, throws

I dont think I can better specify the question...

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190161/difference-between-java-lang-runtimeexception-and-java-lang-exception

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of such exceptions are called "runtime exceptions". `RuntimeException` for an example.

Comment: But why are only RuntimeExceptions thrown by default?

Comment: @suspicious read [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html): *RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions. Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary*.

Comment: @suspicious An inventor of the Java language made such decision.

Comment: But what does default exception throwing has to do with the fact that they are unchecked? I think you are confusing the question. And don't mark it a duplicate luiggi. ITS NOT!

Comment: @suspicious What do you mean by "default exception throwing"?

Comment: @v.ladynev let me demonstrate with an example. I have a method called division() that performs a division by zero.
I call this method from the main method. In the division() method i have not included a "try{ } catch() { }" block, nor have I included the "throws ArithmeticException" when declaring my method. But when I call the method from main it goes like this:
try
{
   division();
}
catch(ArithmeticException e)
{
   System.out.println("Division by zero detected");
}
And even though I have not used "throws ArithmeticException" when declaring my method, the exception handling in "main" worked

Comment: @suspicious In the real systems you will not do such kind of things `try { division(); } catch(ArithmeticException e) { System.out.println("Division by zero detected"); } ` you will just allow an `ArithmeticException` goes to the top level :) Exception "worked" because of the type of it "runtime exception".

Comment: @v.ladynev It doesn't matter what you do in real life for christ's sake. Did you ven understand me?

Comment: @suspicious I am not sure. Ok. You don't need to declare  `ArithmeticException` in the `throws` clause because of it descendant of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: @v.ladynev so the main function, in my example (with is the caller) will deal with the exception anyway, even if the division() method doesn't declare "throws Arithmetic Exception" ?

Comment: @suspicious Yeah. You got it. Checked exceptions are bullshit in my opinion. You should always be ready to have an exception rising in any part of the code.

Comment: @v.ladynev you are awesome sir!

Comment: @suspicious you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Anything inherited from `RuntimeException` or `Error`.

The first means some unhandled issues in your code, the Error means serious problem with JVM like out of memory, stack overflow etc.

Comment: `Error`s are not `Exception`s.

Comment: `Error is not Exception.`

Comment: Well, you're right guys. But I think it's worth mentioning that there are other classes apart from Exception which can surprise you and your code should be aware of