# C# InvalidEnumArgumentException in Java

Tags: java, c#, exception

Is there something similar to the [InvalidEnumArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.invalidenumargumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in java?

Usecase:

```
public FigureType determinateFigureType(int row, int column) throws ??? {
    switch (globalSheet[row][column]) {
        case FIELD_FREE:
            return FigureType.Free;
        case FIELD_A:
            return FigureType.A;
        case FIELD_B:
            return FigureType.B;
        default:
            throw new ???();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe `IllegalArgumentException`?

[Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

There is also an `EnumConstantNotPresentException`, however, this doesn't seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I used an `RuntimeException` now instead of an `IllegalArgumentException`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2190177/4300087 for further informations. With a RuntimeException the `throws ???` part can be omitted.

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException` is a subclass of `RuntimeException`, therefore you can omit the `throws` as well.