# Difference between throwing IOException and RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

Why when I throw a `RuntimeException` inside of a method I don't get any error but when I throw an `IOException` inside of a method I need to throw the exception from the method as well?

```
public void throwException() {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

This works fine. The same thing happens when I throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, `NullPointerException` and `InputMismatchException` and so on.

But when I throw `IOException`, the method has to throw an `IOException` too:

```
public void throwException() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `RuntimeException` is an unchecked exception, and you do not need to mark your method as throwing this exception.  From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> Because the Java programming language does not require methods to catch or to specify unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException, Error, and their subclasses), programmers may be tempted to write code that throws only unchecked exceptions or to make all their exception subclasses inherit from RuntimeException.

As the name implies, you are not expected to check for such a runtime exception, hence the language spec does not require you to mark the method with `throws`.

Answer (score 1):

`IOException` is a (so to say) regular exception, and it's not a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which is a superclass of a special kind of exception.

Taken from the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) (emphasys mine)

> RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that **can be
>   thrown during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine**.
>
> **RuntimeException and its subclasses are unchecked exceptions**.
>   **Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method** or
>   constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of
>   the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or
>   constructor boundary.

Answer (score 0):

You are basicly asking this question. IOException is a more specific Java.Lang.Exception

[Difference between java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190161/difference-between-java-lang-runtimeexception-and-java-lang-exception)