# Does close() method of the Closeable interface has exception in the signature

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception, autocloseable

I was reading Closeable and AutoCloseable interface for the first time.
As per my understanding we can't throw any exception apart from the IOException from close method of the Closeable interface and we can throw any possible exception like IllegalStateException only throw AutoCloseable Interface.
But can we say that close() method of the Closeable method has exception in the signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to ask if `Closable.close()` has exception in the method signature?

Yes it does, you can check the documentation here: [`Closeable.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html#close()). It throws `IOException`.

```java
void close() throws Exception
```

As per the documentation, `Closeable` extends `AutoCloseable`. We use it specifically dedicated to IO streams. Therefore it throws `IOException` instead of `Exception`.

From [`AutoCloseable.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html#close()):

> While this interface method is declared to throw Exception, implementers are strongly encouraged to declare concrete implementations of the close method to throw more specific exceptions, or to throw no exception at all if the close operation cannot fail.

Answer (score 3):

The [AutoCloseable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) defines the `close` method as follows:

```
void close() throws Exception
```

Whereas `close` in the [Closeable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html), which extends `AutoCloseable`, is defined like this:

```
void close() throws IOException
```

Therefore you can only throw `IOException` or any exception extending from it in the latter case.

Please note that you can always throw any (unchecked) runtime exceptions like [IllegalStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) independent of the exceptions defined on the method signature.

Comment: so that means that even void close() throws IOException this can throw IllegalStateException right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you look at the class hierarchy of `IllegalStateException` you will see that it extends from `RuntimeException`. As mentioned before, you can throw any runtime exception (also known as "unchecked exceptions") independent of the exceptions defined in the method signature. You might also want to review this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190161/difference-between-java-lang-runtimeexception-and-java-lang-exception