# How to Prevent IOException with the File Class

Tags: java, windows, file, ioexception

I've been trying to get an image to be saved as a BufferedImage in my program, but every time I try to set the file pathname it always results in an IOException error.

```
File grass = new File("C:\\\\Users\\user\\eclipse-workspace\\minecraft\\textures\\GRASS.png");
    
    private final BufferedImage grassTexture = ImageIO.read(grass);

    private final BufferedImage dirtTexture = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\eclipse-workspace\\\\minecraft\\\\textures\\\\DIRT.png"));
```

As you can see I tried a couple of different patterns of backslashes. ^

I use Eclipse for my IDE and it gave me this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException
Unhandled exception type IOException

```
at minecraft.MinecraftGame.<init>(MinecraftGame.java:28)
at minecraft.MinecraftGame.main(MinecraftGame.java:151)
```

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: This is a compile time error. Methods can throw Exceptions, you need to add code for the case that happens, likely a try/catch is what you want.

Comment: Give yourself a break - use single forward slashes. They'll work perfectly well although you shouldn't be mixing data directories into your dev tree

Comment: Not a perfect match, but please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190659/1531124 ... when you have a *checked* exception (like IOException) in the signature of a method that you are calling, then your code has to handle it. This is really basic stuff, and the reasonable way here: pick up a good book about Java. This place isnt a replacement for you doing that LEARNING part.

Answer (score 0):

Get used to the fact that computer programs may face problems at runtime.
That means that not everything will be going as smooth as a developer might believe in.

Exceptions are a way to report errors. Preventing them would mean making sure that no exception will ever occur. Good, that is the perfect case a developer might have dreamt of. Reality is different.

So the compiler just warns you (the developer) that you have not designed your code for the fact that something might have gone wrong. The magic is not to prevent an exception but to define what should happen in case one occurs.

One way to deal with (and done by many beginners) is to just catch the exception and forget about it. A much better way is to mark your method that it might throw an exception. If you do this it would mean your application terminates on any error. But the user would be aware of it. And as developer you could learn when to come up with better strategies.

So change lines that look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

into that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
```

until you know better.